# Reducing log output on webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a Webpack 4 project, when using webpack-dev-server I got a lot of logging when a build is complete which I really do not need.

```
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
‼ ｢wdm｣: Built at: 2018-4-15 09:15:18
Entrypoint main = styles.css bundle.js
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main}
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.75 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js
3.58 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main}
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main}
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main}
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {main}
[./source/scripts/components/app.js] 2.11 KiB {main} [1 warning]
[./source/scripts/index.js] 454 bytes {main}
[./source/styles/main.scss] 39 bytes {main} [built]
   [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./source/scripts/index.js 40 bytes {main}
    + 36 hidden modules

WARNING in ./source/scripts/components/app.js

C:\...\source\scripts\components\app.js
  3:1  warning  Component should be written as a pure function  react/prefer-stateless-function

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

 @ ./source/scripts/index.js 11:11-38
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./source/scripts/index.js
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js!source/styles/main.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css 6.42 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin}
    [./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js!./source/styles/main.scss] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./source/styles/main.scss 293 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
    [./node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js] 2.21 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin}
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

Is there any way to reduce this to just the important things? Output similar to this would be ideal

```
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
‼ ｢wdm｣: Built at: 2018-4-15 09:15:18

WARNING in ./source/scripts/components/app.js

C:\...\source\scripts\components\app.js
  3:1  warning  Component should be written as a pure function  react/prefer-stateless-function

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

My current webpack.config.js has the following:

```
module.exports ={
    // ...
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
        publicPath: BUILD_DIR,
        quiet: false,
        noInfo: false,
        stats: {
            assets: false,
            colors: true,
            version: false,
            hash: false,
            timings: false,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false,
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Just needed to read the documentation a bit more..

I've managed to get my output down to:

```
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
‼ ｢wdm｣: Built at: 2018-4-15 09:36:12

WARNING in ./source/scripts/components/app.js

C:\code\land-calculator\source\scripts\components\app.js
  3:1  warning  Component should be written as a pure function  react/prefer-stateless-function

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

 @ ./source/scripts/index.js 11:11-38
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./source/scripts/index.js
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

To do so I updated my stats settings to the following:

```
module.exports ={
    // ...
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
        publicPath: BUILD_DIR,
        quiet: false,
        noInfo: false,
        stats: {
            assets: false,
            children: false,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false,
            colors: true,
            entrypoints: false,
            hash: false,
            modules: false,
            timings: false,
            version: false,
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For webpack 5, its a little different. You will use stats directly inside the export object instead of inside the "devServer" property

```
module.exports = {
  ....
  stats: 'minimal' // 'minimal', 'errors-only', 'errors-warnings', 'none', 'normal', 'verbose', 'detailed', 'summary'
}
```

You can check the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/) for more info